# Is there a difference between TimeZoneInfo instances for .NET 3.5 on Windows compared to Mono on OS X?

Tags: mono, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to call EWS (Exchange version 2007 SP1) using Mono on OS X. I can connect to the service and authenticate, but any calls I try to make result in an exception as follows:

**Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException** has been thrown
"A time zone with the specified ID could not be found."

I've tried specifying several different IDs and all result in the same response. I'm starting to wonder if the TZI ids themselves are different between platforms. If so, does anyone know how to resolve the differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a difference between time zone ids on the two systems. I used the following code to loop through the timezones on each system and note the differences for the timezones I was interested in using:

```
    foreach (TimeZoneInfo tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()){
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", tz.Id,
                           tz.DisplayName, tz.StandardName, tz.DaylightName);

            }
```

Then I used the *CreateCustomTimeZone* method to build an instance that mimicked the Windows settings:

```
    TimeZoneInfo newtz = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("Central Standard Time",
               tzi.BaseUtcOffset, "(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)", 
               "Central Standard Time");
```

and I used that instance in the service call. I'm guessing I only needed to get the ID right (I set the offset, long name, etc as well).

Comment: In order to get accurate time responses from the service calls it is important to get the rest of the TimeZoneInfo attributes correct. I included the offset rules in the second set of code above like so:
`TimeZoneInfo newtz = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("Central Standard Time", tzi.BaseUtcOffset, 
                                                          "(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)", "Central Standard Time",
                                                          "Central Daylight Time", tzi.GetAdjustmentRules());`